# Firebase Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

For some reason, firebase can't read the property UID. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Should I be changing how I am getting the data from firebase.auth in the first place? The end goal is to update a firestore database file with the ID of the user UID.

```
    // Add additional info to user account
const completeAccountform = document.querySelector('#wf-form-completeAccount');
document.getElementById("completeButton").addEventListener('click', addAccountinfo);

function addAccountinfo() {
    // get new account data
    const firstName = completeAccountform['firstName'].value;
    const lastName = completeAccountform['lastName'].value;
    const location = completeAccountform['location'].value;

    const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
            email: signupForm['signupEmail'].value,
            firstname: completeAccountform['firstName'].value,
            lastname: completeAccountform['lastName'].value,
            location: completeAccountform['location'].value
    }).then(function(docRef) {
        modalContainer.style.display = 'none'
        console.log("Document updated with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });

    form.reset()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to follow the recoomendations at the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) for retrieveng the current user, as it i specified:

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer
> on the Auth object:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

> By using an observer, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an
> intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current
> user. When you use signInWithRedirect, the onAuthStateChanged observer
> waits until getRedirectResult resolves before triggering.

I'd recommend you to use the observer, because sometimes the auth object has not finished initializing and it'll be null (then you'll have this error). It depends on your Auth flow and what fits your user case better

Comment: Thanks for this @chinoche! Solved my problem! I was calling a function to get user info from a DB before the UID was populated! I already had a function called handleAuthStateChanged that utilised onAuthStateChanged, but I was basically trying to get the user info in two places when it should have just been in handleAuthStateChanged. Thanks again!